# What reason could a Mind Flayer colony get involved with lycanthropy?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-development, lycanthropy

Recently I ended a campaign centered around lycanthropy where a few lycantropes were acidentally let loose and wild, in the same world with other players I hinted towards mindfalyers starting to make a presence in the world. I was asking myself could there be a reason for mindflayers to get involved with lycanthropy? Maybe even get infected? My idea being to mix both things for the next campaing. Like a colony becoming infected or something along the lines.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the Stack! Unfortunately, our format here is mostly focused on questions with either factual or experiential "best answers" rather than idea-generation like what you're asking for. Your question looks like it will be voted closed soon as "opinion-based"--but might I recommend any of the bigger D&D focused forums, or the D&D subreddit? They're much more suited to the sort of discussion you're looking for. :)

Comment: And here's our [curated list of fora](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) we suggest for such an occasion, including our very own [chat].